# How do I install deepplantphenomics python package from github?

Tags: python, git, package

I've tried using this
`pip install ./deepplantphenomics`

However, it comes up with this error.
ERROR: Invalid requirement: './deepplantphenomics'

After some research, I ended up trying this command

```
pip install git+git://github.com/p2irc/deepplantphenomics.git
```

Instead, it was stuck on cloning even after left for hours

Cloning git://github.com/p2irc/deepplantphenomics.git to c:\users\zaen\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-5oc6mfeo

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository using the command describe in the git:

```
git clone https://github.com/p2irc/deepplantphenomics.git
```

Then just access the newly created folder deepplantphenomics and type inside it:

```
pip install .
```

That will download the dependencies and build the wheel. After that go to a different folder and try to import the module. It should be successfully loaded.